# An Idiom as a reality

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, metaphors

Is there a word to describe when you use an idiom to describe reality ?

Examples : Raining cats and dogs and it is actually raining cats and dogs, Boxed in and you are actually surrounded by boxes.

Answer (score 5):

Idioms are normally interpreted figuratively, that is, the words taken together don't mean what each word individually means. If the idiom is actually describing reality, it has become **literal**.

> It is ***literally*** raining cats and dogs - I just got hit with a poodle!

Comment: Siamese is the worst

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, ***for real***

> *Slang* Truly so in fact or actuality: "Is this place for real? A wolf in a ... leisure suit and a cow in a print dress wait patiently on the couch in the lobby" (Teresa Carson). [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+real)

Answer (score 0):

[*Actually*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/actually) will convey the sentiment here, both in denotation,

> used to refer to what is true or real

and with a better connotation than alternatives.

> used to stress that a statement is true especially when it differs in some way from what might have been thought or expected

Please note that [*literally*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/literally) [does not exclusively have the same meaning as it previously had](http://www.cnn.com/2013/08/15/living/literally-definition/), and will validly be interpreted to mean the opposite of what you are saying:

> in effect :  virtually

I would avoid *literally* in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Idioms don't work that way. However, there are a few expressions that has both literal and figurative senses.

For example, consider ***[out on a limb](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+on+a+limb)***

> 1. *Lit*. out on a limb of a tree where it is dangerous.
> 2. *Fig*. in a dangerous position to do something; at risk.

[The Free Dictionary]

> Don't *go out on a limb*, by ***going out on a limb*** of a tree!

*figurative* | ***literal***

All you gotta do is explore more such idioms and phrases!